# div height does not change when the height of other objects in page change

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

there is this problem that I have and I don't seem to find an answer for.
On my website in my posts, I have added a box to download stuff. when someone clicks on that box, the ul corresponding to that box opens using a javascript onclick function.
now the problem is that the height of the parrent div does not change when this happens so my template does not work correctly.
I can see that "PVII Equal Height Columns 2 script" is used on the parrent div which adds a height property to that div automatically.
I tried fixing it by adding some javascript to rewrite the height whenever I click on the download box but that does not seem to work.
you can see the situation in link below :
http://mrcode.ir/?p=128
just click on the green box in the middle of the page (the one that has a folder) and take a look at the footer so you'll see what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: it works for me what browser you use?

Comment: thanks for testing. i use chrome and firefox. but it only works when i change the size of my browser or when i click on green box before the load is finished

Comment: Sorry, but that is a bit difficult to debug. Could you make a smaller example that behaves the same way? In a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for instance? Oh, and the text "Color ^", is that by design? I mean, I don't read Hebrew, so the "Color" stands out like a sore thumb. (The piece of PHP on top had me going too, until I saw it was part of the graphic.)

Comment: well the website is in Persian language :) . that "Color ^" that you talk about is actually color with a number 8 which is a part of the text not the design so it's nothing to worry about. sadly i have no idea how to recreate the problem there. i am not much of an expert. but i still guess that it has something to do with "PVII Equal Height Columns script".